# How to export only part of a big mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, export, dump

We have a mysql database several GB in size. As we are developing on our local machines, we need a convenient way to export and import it.

We need to export only part of the whole DB. Is there a way to:

Select some range from table for instance `customer` an then select from other tables only rows that are pointed from or are pointing to the rows we just selected from the `customer` table and then recursively go deeper?

Or what are the other ways to accomplish exporting only part of the whole database in a way that it won't get corrupted?

Comment: is your database partitioned? if not partition it horizontally on some range that fits your need and export the partition